# Do we have a callback method for finalizing rendering in react reconciler?

Tags: reactjs, react-fiber, reconcile

I'm writing a custom renderer using react reconciler.

My renderer should call `computeLayout` when the tree got some changes.

I can insert `computeLayout` function call at the tail of `appendChild`, `removeChild`, `commitUpdate` which causes changes in the tree. But it would be painfully inefficient when there are multiple calls of those functions triggered by a single state update.

What I need is some sort of batching.
But if I use `requestanimationframe` to batch `computeLayout`, then users can see the wrong layout for a moment.

I want react reconciler to call my `computeLayout` after every tree modification is applied and just before it terminates allowing browsers to apply all DOM updates.
Do we have such a callback method? Can I use `resetAfterCommit` method in this case?